# How do I get invited to realms?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do you get invited into realms? Does someone from mojong have to invite you? If they do invite you do you have to pay? And finally is realms local or online? I am able to play regular multiplayer though.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Pocket Edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Realms, 
I live in Sweden but **people from all over the world can play on the server** once I've invited them.

**It's free to play**. You only need the invitation (**the Realms owner has to know your game name to be able to send you an invitation**), other than that it works pretty much the same as regular servers. The game it self is the same.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for contributing to gaming.stackexchange.com. Unfortunately, while your answer is well worded and concise, it does not in fact answer the question that's actually being *asked* -- The question was regarding how to be invited into an existing Realms server, not about how to set one up for yourself...

Comment: I answererd the questions if you read them your self -  "the Realms owner has to know your game name to be able to send you an invitation", "it is free to play" "player all over the world can join" -  and also gave some additional info - why is that wrong?

Comment: When the additional information is three times as long as the actual answer, it starts muddying the issue - especially when the additional information reads as a diatribe or a personal peeve. Best to stick on topic.

Comment: That is your very personal view in the matter. I was just trying to be helpful. If you want ppl to leave the forums, you are doing a good job.

Comment: @Sun Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a forum. Posts are expected to answer the question at hand, and not provide too much extraneous information. It's how things work here. To that effect, I've edited it out of your post. If you'd like to understand a bit more, you might want to check out [answer].